# java:how to get value of 1 variable of 1 form into another form

Tags: java, netbeans

I am having two forms, 1st is form_1 and 2nd is form_2. form_1 containing one textfield photo_id_num. I am getting its value by .getText method.

```
public String getID()
{
    String id1=photo_id_num.getText(); 
    return(id1);
}
```

Now I want to access this value into 2nd form. Code for 2nd form is

```
 Form_1 frm=new Form_1();
 String id2=frm.getID();
 System.out.println("ID2="+id2);
```

but it doesn't work. Please help me.

Comment: How do you define - _it doesn't work_ ?

Comment: I am using netbeans. So I have taken photo_id_num as a variable name of textfield. and i want to retrive the value of that textfield into 2nd form.

Comment: What problem are you facing? Your code seems alright.

Comment: I am not getting value of ID2 in the 2nd form i.e. second code. :(

Comment: What is it printing? Any exceptions?

Comment: No, it is neither giving any exception, nor any value of ID2. It is returning blank.

Comment: It should atleast print "ID2=" on your console. Did you try printing the `String id1` within the `getID()` method?

Comment: Yup, its priting ID2= on console. and I have tried to print ID1 in the getID() method. Its printing values in the form_1. It is not printing value in 2nd form.

Comment: Some answers below suggest some useful things. Besides, if you need that value in your second form,you will probably need to use `setText()` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you are creating a new `Form_1` before you call `getId` on it. You need to use the `JTextField` that was already created and use it to set the Form's ID. Look in the generated code for the variable name of the text field and get the text from that field. Use that text to set the ID in the form and then call getId on form_1 and use what's returned in a setText for the other field.

**Edit** Looking at your getId again I see that you have a design issue. Read up about [coupling](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_%28computer_programming%29) and [cohesion](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohesion_%28computer_science%29). It will make your life much easier.

Answer (score 2):

In form1 interface

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
String id=jTextField1.getText();
form2 form=new form2(id);
form.setVisible(true);
// TODO add your handling code here:
    }
```

In form2 Interface

public class form2 extends javax.swing.JFrame {

```
/** Creates new form form2 */
public form2(String id) {
    initComponents();
    String id1=id;
    jTextField1.setText(id1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

look at your console output, may be some Null Pointer exception is thrown

Comment: No, it is neither giving any exception, nor any value of ID2. It is returning blank

Answer (score 0):

```
Form_1 frm=new Form_1();
String id2=frm.getID();
```

Allow the entry of the ID in the form before using the value. If both the forms are opened from the same source it will be useful to pass the `Form_1` object to `Form_2` rather than creating a `Form_1` in `Form_2`